# Flask OpenCV Send and Receive Images in Bytes

Tags: python, api, opencv, flask

I want to send and receive images in bytes in my flask API. I also want to send some json alongside the image. How can I achieve this?

Below is my current solution that does not work

flask:

```
    @app.route('/add_face', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def add_face():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print(request.json)
        nparr = np.fromstring(request.form['img'], np.uint8)
        print(request.form['img'])
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        cv2.imshow("frame", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    return "list of names & faces"
```

client:

```
def save_encoding(img_file):
    URL = "http://localhost:5000/add_face"
    img = open(img_file, 'rb').read()

    response = requests.post(URL, data={"name":"obama", "img":str(img)})
    print(response.content)
```

produced error:

```
cv2.imshow("frame", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? In what way?

Comment: What is the error/exception are you getting?

Comment: @randomir updated error

Comment: @IshanBhatt updated error

Comment: What does len(request.form[img]) and nparr.shape return? Before that, did you check img variable is correct at client side?

Comment: img variable is correct at client side. `request.form[img']` gets the image in bytes that was sent from client side. `request.form['name']` would return the name sent by client. `nparr.shape` returns the dimensions numpy array (same as dimensions of the image)

Comment: With what does that return I mean did you check whether those values are correct, what is shape of your img variable after decode then.

Comment: @unlut the shape of the img is 0x0 after decode. it means that something wrong happened in decoding phase.

Comment: Is it possible to upload your image?

Answer (score 4):

The following has worked for me. 
I don't have the client code but I have a curl request. That should do the trick,

SERVER

```
from flask import request
from PIL import Image
import io

@app.route("/add_face", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    image = request.files["image"]
    image_bytes = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image.read()))
```

CLIENT SIDE

```
curl -X POST -F image=@PATH/TO/FILE 'http://localhost:5000/add_face'
```

Comment: but this would be slower if you have a continuous stream of frames between a server and client

Comment: No idea about that, I hit requests sporadically, So never felt it. 
You can wrap your flask app with gunicorn or gevent if you like.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to send images in base64 format, by doing that you get rid of problems about sending/receiving binary data since you just work with a string. Also it is more convenient in web stuff. Tested code below:
Server side:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/add_face', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_face():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #  read encoded image
        imageString = base64.b64decode(request.form['img'])

        #  convert binary data to numpy array
        nparr = np.fromstring(imageString, np.uint8)

        #  let opencv decode image to correct format
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);
        cv2.imshow("frame", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    return "list of names & faces"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Client side:

```
import requests
import base64

URL = "http://localhost:5000/add_face"

#  first, encode our image with base64
with open("block.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    img = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

response = requests.post(URL, data={"name":"obama", "img":str(img)})
print(response.content)
```

You can use COLOR instead of ANYCOLOR if you are sure about your input images.

Comment: still generates same error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Then please answer my question in the comments. What does len(request.form[img]) and nparr.shape return? Before that, did you check img variable is correct at client side?

Comment: I have answered it